# Replacing values in dataframe by index value

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a subset of data in a dataframe df1 that needs to be corrected. Suppose I extract the bad data into dfbad dataframe. Once I have cleaned the data in dfbad how do I use the dataframe index values in dfbad to replace the the bad data from the original df1. My index values in df1 are unique per row.

- df1                             - dfbad
- 1  Value                       1 NewValue
- 3  Value                       3 NewValue
- 5  Value                       5 NewValue

The numbers represent dataframe index values. I want to replace Value with NewValue for all columns

Comment: provide sample data please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought it was more complex. Once changes have been fixed just did update

```
df1.update(dfbad)
```